# excel vba - splitting a very complicated string

Tags: string, excel, vba

I have received a worksheet in Excel which contains kids names and video time tags all in one column, and I need to sort this into a logical format so I can use it. However, the list has no separators.. So I am hoping someone could help me out with a VBA Excel macro.

Below is an example (shortened) string, lets say this is in Cell A1.

" Sandy 25:1132:27Giorgio
 09:1114:7Anne Marie 32:10David 17:48Marty
 04:3506:1010:3613:1014:32Sandy (2) 04:30Brian 13:4714:37"

I would ideally like for the string to be split up into cells as follows

Cell A2 Sandy

Cell A3 25:11

Cell A4 32:27

Cell A5 Giorgio

Cell A6 09:11

Cell A7 14:7

Cell A8 Anne Marie

Cell A9 32:10

Cell A10 David

Cell A11 17:48

Cell A12 Marty

Cell A13 04:35

Cell A14 06:10

Cell A15 10:36

Cell A16 13:10

Cell A17 14:32

Cell A18 Sandy (2)

Cell A19 04:30

Cell A20 Brian

Cell A21 13:47

Cell A22 14:37

I have tried using some basic "find" and "len" formulas but no luck..

Comment: What macro did you try writing ? Are you expecting us to write the entire macro for you ?

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't do exactly what you want - but it may help get you going in a direction...  Hopefully it'll turn out to be the right one...

I pasted your string into cell `A1` in my worksheet and then wrote this code in a module in the sheet:-

```
Function parseText(ByVal text As String, ByVal domain As Integer) As String
    Dim returnValue As String
    Dim colon As Integer
    Dim soFar As Integer
    soFar = 0
    text = Trim(text)
    While soFar < domain
        colon = InStr(text, ":")
        While (Mid(text, colon + 5, 1) = ":")
            colon = colon + 5
        Wend
        returnValue = Mid(text, 1, colon + 2)
        While Not (IsNumeric(Right(returnValue, 1)))
            returnValue = Left(returnValue, Len(returnValue) - 1)
        Wend
        text = Replace(text, returnValue, "")
        soFar = soFar + 1
    Wend
    parseText = returnValue
End Function

Function parseDomain(ByVal domain As String) As String
    Dim returnValue As String
    Dim part As String
    While Len(domain) > 0
        part = ""
        If InStr(domain, ":") > 0 Then
            part = Mid(domain, InStrRev(domain, ":") - 2, 5)
            returnValue = part & "~" & returnValue
            domain = Left(domain, Len(domain) - Len(part))
        End If
        If part = "" Then
            returnValue = Trim(domain) & "~" & Left(returnValue, Len(returnValue) - 1)
            domain = ""
        End If
    Wend
    parseDomain = returnValue
End Function

Function pullPiece(ByVal block As String, ByVal piece As Integer) As String
    Dim returnValue As String
    Dim pieces() As String
    pieces = Split(block, "~")
    If piece > UBound(pieces) + 1 Then
        returnValue = ""
    Else
        returnValue = pieces(piece - 1)
    End If
    pullPiece = returnValue
End Function
```

This bit is complicated to explain...

In the image below the formula in `A14` is the content of cell `A4`.  The formula in `A15` is the content of cell `A5`, etc. all the way down to `A10`.  These formulae break out the block of text for each name.

The formula in `B14` is the content of `B4`.  This cell can then be copied down the range to `B10` so that the references change to `A4` thru `A10`.  These formulae reformat the text with tildes so that the text is easier to split up (later).

The formula in `C14` is the contents of `C4`.  This cell can be copied down to `C10`.  This pulls the name from the block it relates to.  The second parameter is the "piece" number - 1=name, 2=time1, 3=time2, etc.

The formula in `D14` is the contents of cells `D4` and pulls the first time out of the block it relates to.  I haven't put the definition for the other formulae - but hopefully you can see the pattern on how they are used.

[image: sheet with formula usage]

Drop me a message if you want any clarification.

Answer (score 0):

The string is difficult to parse due to the timestamps not appearing to follow a similar format. For example most follow the format **00:00**, however the value you wish to place in cell **A7** only has a single digit following the colon. I have therefore created some code to get you started in the right direction, but this works on the assumption of the format **00.00** and currently doesn't parse text following numbers. But if you perform a bit more research I'm sure you can complete from this point:

```
Public Sub TestCode()

Dim strTest As String, strModify() As String, strNew() As String, x As Long

strTest = "Sandy 25:1132:27Giorgio 09:1114:7Anne Marie 32:10David 17:48Marty 04:3506:1010:3613:1014:32Sandy (2) 04:30Brian 13:4714:37"

strModify = Split(strTest)

ReDim strNew(0 To 0)
strNew(0) = strModify(0)
For x = 1 To UBound(strModify)
    If Left(strModify(x), 1) Like "[A-Z]" Then
        ReDim Preserve strNew(0 To (UBound(strNew) + 1))
        strNew(UBound(strNew)) = strModify(x)
    ElseIf Left(strModify(x), 1) Like "[0-9]" Then
        Do Until InStr(1, strModify(x), ":") = 0
            ReDim Preserve strNew(0 To (UBound(strNew) + 1))
            strNew(UBound(strNew)) = Left(strModify(x), InStr(1, strModify(x), ":") + 2)
            strModify(x) = Right(strModify(x), Len(strModify(x)) - (InStr(1, strModify(x), ":") + 2))
        Loop
    Else
        strNew(UBound(strNew)) = strNew(UBound(strNew)) & " " & strModify(x)
   End If
Next x

For x = 0 To UBound(strNew)
    Range("A1").Offset(0, x).Value = strNew(x)
Next x

End Sub
```

To help you understand the code in order to modify, this is basically splitting the original string wherever there is a space (result placed in array called **strModify**). It then checks the first character in the string to see if it is a letter, number or other character. Based on this information it will place the individual components of the string in to a new array variable called **strNew**. It then simply reads this array and places each item in to the next available cell.

I hope this helps you begin. Once you have a solution please post your final code on here in order to help others who may have a similar problem.